# Trouble Connecting to the MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to the MySQL server using MySQLi. It is enabled in the server end where this code runs. I am unable to connect to the server using the following information. Did I miss something? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php
        // DBInfo
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "nc5ff";
        $password = "Ni\$hant809472";
        $dbname = "test";

        // DB Connection
        $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

        /* check connection */
        if (!$link) {
            header("Connection Failure", true, 777);
        }

        mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Get the *actual* error message. Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: For debugging purposes (you don't want to print the whole error message to the client in production code) please apply the error handling code shown in Example #1 at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php and add the error message you get to your question (via the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34638398/edit) link, not as a comment).

Comment: check for the right password .. you seems a bit complex and then could be there is a mistake.

Comment: I'm actually trying to connect to a server. I just got an error saying "Access denied for user 'nc5ff'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". It seems they need to provide server access to me.

Comment: Does your password really contain a "\"? If so then nyou have to escape it using "\\" and escape the `$` by using `\$` resulting in `"Ni\\\$hant809472"`

Comment: @maxhb Do I need the three \\\ or just a single \ ?

Comment: You'll need all 3 of them.

Comment: I'm still getting the access error. I think I might need to contact the server admin for further access. I'm unable to do much even in the mysql terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the password as it contains special php characters (\ and $):

```
$password = "Ni\\\$hant809472";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all of the information right i don't see anything wrong with the code, but please make sure you have all the **information right**.